# How did Apache Spark implement its topK() API?

Tags: apache-spark

In Apache Spark there is an [`RDD.top()` API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), which can return the top *k* elements from an RDD. I'd like to know how this operations is implemented. Does it first sort the RDD then return the top *k* values? Or does it use some other more efficient implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1313

Comment: `top` operation over a type `A` forms a `monoid`, given some sort of ordering. I don't know about the concrete implementation details but that's the idea I imagine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't sort the whole RDD, that operation would be too expensive.

It will rather select *TOP N* elements per each partition separately using a **priority queue**. And then these queues are merged together in the *reduce* operation. That means only small part of the whole RDD is shuffled across the network.

See [`RDD.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1311) for more details.

**Example**:

3 input partitions
`RDD.top(2)`

```
[3, 5, 7, 10], [8, 6, 4, 12], [9, 1, 2, 11]
      ||            ||              || 
   [10, 7]        [12, 8]         [11, 9]
================== reduce ==================
                 [12, 11]
```

Comment: I have to add this doesn't give an accurate result. Imagine we have partitions like `[1:3,2:4,3:4]` and `[1:3,3:6,4:5]` , each entriy is in format of `id:frequency` . Now for `top(2)` we have these two lists `[2:4,3:4]` and `[3:6,4:5]`  for each `local top(2)` and the end result is `[3:10,4:5]` while the right result should be `[1:6,3:10]`.